# Csh Variable Expansion Malfunction

Tags: awk, csh, gawk

I have created a `tcsh` script with a series of `gawk` commands in the following form:

```
gawk -f InputFileName > OutputFileName
```

After the standard call-in (#!/bin/csh -f), I utilized the following command:

```
set a = $<
```

In the `InputFileName`, I proceed to use `${a}.txt`, but it does not even use `$a` when looking up the input file.
They were initially running fine on Cygwin (Windows); now they are running on a Linux and are presenting problems.

Comment: Seems like Dos2Unix is the best solution because I am getting question marks in output files as well.

Comment: `I have created a csh script` - google "csh why not" so you now why not to do that.

Comment: Yes, I hope to transfer to more mainstream, maintained programming languages like Python, Java, C++, and Matlab with larger communities, etc. What do you say? Note: I had already read this completely; I get your point. Thx.

Comment: What is it you hope those other languages will be able to do for you? For any of the tasks I've seen you post here so far all you'd get from any of them would be coding overhead so it just depends what else you are planning to do (e.g. if you are planning to write a high reliability, high availability, multi-user device then maybe C++ would be the way to go). Just figure out what you need to do and find/use the language that's best for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a text file compatibility issue.
Since I did not have dos2unix on my computer, I used the following one line of code.

```
awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }' winfile.txt > unixfile.txt
```